# File writing weird error

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I try to execute this code :

```
file = getFile(file_name)

string = ("Days", " : ", "8")

file.write(bytes(string))
```

I get this weird text in my file:

```
('Days', ' : ', '8')   d                 l                  Z                 g                 Z                 d                �                  Z                 d          
      �                  Z                 d                �                  Z                 d                �                  Z                 d                �                  Z                 d          (      �                  Z                 e          ,      d                 �                 Z                   e          .      e                     j   
              d                   d   
              �                                    e          0      d                 d                 �                  G                   H                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           � �  � S 8�
```

I would also like to remove the brackets over

> Days : 8

Comment: What is the _desired_ output? Did you realize writing your data as `bytes`? Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to reproduce your behaviour.

Comment: What is `getFile`? How do you create `string` and why not simply `string = "Days : 8"`? Why are you trying to write this as binary?

Comment: seems like an encoding issue also your string is not a string but a tuple

Comment: `bytes(string)` raises `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. A working example helps!

Comment: You can get weird things like that if you open an existing file, `seek(0)` and then write.

Comment: You are going to get nowhere with this question unless you give us something we can test with. You've got some magical `getFile` and then you show us `file.write(bytes(string))` which can't work with the given `string` and can't produce the output you show.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the brackets. 
Remove them on the string = line and put

so change:
string = ("Days", " : ", "8")
to:
string = "Days"+" : "+"8"

That should work for that section.

Also:

Change this line to improve the output
from:
file.write(bytes(string))

to:
file.write(string)

remove the bytes section (unless it is a requires library that is needed, that may be causing your error!)